# Powershell extract values from file

Tags: powershell

I have a log file that has a lot of fields listed in it. I want to extract the fields out of the file, but I don't want to search through the file line by line.

I have my pattern:

```
$pattern="Hostname \(Alias\):(.+)\(.+Service: (.+)"
```

This will give me the two values that I need. I know that if I have a string, and I'm looking for one match I can use the $matches array to find the fields. In other words, If I'm looking at a single line in the file using the string variable $line, I can extract the fields using this code.

```
if($line -matches $pattern){
  $var1=$matches[1]
  $var2=$matches[2]
}
```

But how can I get these values without searching line by line? I want to pass the whole file as a single string, and add the values that I am extracting to two different arrays.

I'm looking for something like

```
while($filetext -match $pattern){
  $array1+=$matches[1]
  $array2+=$matches[2]
}
```

But this code puts me in an infinite loop if there is even one match. So is there a nextMatch function I can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PowerShell 2.0 addressed this limitation by adding the `-AllMatches` parameter to the `Select-String` cmdlet e.g.:

```
$filetext | Select-String $pattern -AllMatches | 
    Foreach {$_.Matches | Foreach {$_.Groups[1] | Foreach {$_.Value}}}
```